# Loading of all the controls in each tabitem on firing the events in SWT

Tags: java, swt, tabitem

I have used `setSelection` to set the index of the to be selected tab and `notifyListener` to fire back the events captured. But while firing the tabs are not loading completely, there is just blank page. So Please help me out.

Comment: Please post a minimal version of your code that illustrates your problem.

Comment: I am using tabfolder.addListener to get the events. Then  tabfolder.setSelection(event.getSelect()); and  kids.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, new Event()); to playback the events captured. getSelect() gives the index of the tab selected. The problem is during playback the tabs are being selected but the controls present within the tab(like other buttons,combo,etc) are not displayed.

Comment: You need to show us a minimal version of your code. There is far too little information here for us to be able to help.